# io module error when importing Bokeh / python

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm having some trouble using Bokeh on my system (Fedora). I have installed it successfully using `pip install bokeh`. I am able to serve some of the examples using `bokeh serve --show example.py`, but I'm unable to `import bokeh` in python. I get the error:

```
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jun 20 2016, 14:45:23) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bokeh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "bokeh.py", line 12, in <module>
    from bokeh.io import curdoc
ImportError: No module named io
```

I have tried upgrading bokeh, but that didn't help. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: What version of bokeh did pip report as being installed? `bokeh.io` was added roughly a year ago, but perhaps even an upgrade on whatever version of Fedora you are using is too old.

Comment: pip doesn't seem to be telling me what version I have, and since I can't import bokeh without an error, I can't check the version that way either. D you know how I can confirm the version?

Comment: I have now successfully installed bokeh-0.12.1.dev3 and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Definitely some kind of installation / configuration issue. Hard to say more without poking around your  `site-packages` directory. Can you try creating a virtualenv? Alternatively using the free Anaconda python distribution might help.

Comment: Hmm opening a new terminal seems to have fixed the problem. Perhaps a reboot is in order. Thanks.